# Find the reduced R for each of these (block) matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the reduced R for each of these (block) matrices: B=

$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    A & A 
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

C = $$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    A & A  \\
A & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

The solution is :
Rb=[Ra, Ra]
Rc=$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    R_A & 0  \\
0 & R_A
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
zero rows go to the bottom

I can understand Rb, but I cannot understand Rc. I can give an explicit example of A, then I find Rc form is correct. But why is that?

Comment: What is the "reduced R" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie reduced row echelon forms R